# Remove date from x axis in 24h histogram in R (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have stripped the date from my timestamps in a dataset so I can plot the logins by  the hour.

```
MV1$starttime <- format(MV1$earliestlog,format='%H:%M:%S')
MV1$starttime <- as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date(), MV1$starttime),  #Adds todays date
                                    format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

When I plot it with

```
MV1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = starttime)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=30, ) +
  labs(title = "logins vs daytime between 2018 and 2020",
       subtitle = "Source: , Bin size = 30",
       x = "Time of day",
       y = "logins")
```

[image: Histogram]
I get what I want, except I want to remove todays date from the x axis and only keep hourly time labels.

I tried adding

```
+ scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date(), "00:00"))),
                   labels=c("00:00"))
```

but I get this error:

Error in `new_mapped_discrete()`:
! `mapped_discrete` objects can only be created from numeric vectors

I also tried to get rid of the date in my df, but that does not seem to work either / is then not graphable as that is only a character column then. Looks like POSIX needs a date...

```
MV1$starttime <- format(as.POSIXct(strptime(MV1$starttime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="")), format='%H:%M:%S')
MV1$starttime <- as_date(MV1$starttime)
```

Any idea how I can just remove the date from the x axis in the graph and maybe even add some more labels at every full hour or so?

TIA!

Comment: [`hms::as_hms()`](https://hms.tidyverse.org/reference/hms.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try formatting the labels of the x-axis using `scale_x_datetime()` and change the default labels by setting `date_format` to `"%H:00"` ("%H" = hours, see `?strptime` for available format codes). The date breaks can be set with the parameter `date_breaks`, which expects a string with a duration (e.g. "1 hour", "2 hours").

Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Generating some timestamps
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
    timestamp = sample(
      seq(as.POSIXct("2022-04-26 00:00:00"), 
          as.POSIXct("2022-04-27 00:00:00"), by = "sec"),
                size = 1000, replace = TRUE))

# Histogram with formatted date 
ggplot(df, aes(timestamp)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 3600) + 
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 hour", date_labels = "%H:00", 
                   expand = c(0, 0))
```

Hope this helps.